# Finding partial-match to item in list-of-lists

Tags: python

I have list of lists like this:

```
l = [["08:00", "09:00", 60, False, 1.0],
     ["09:00", "10:00", 60, False, 0.3],
     ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, 2.0],]
```

I want to check if list `l` have a element but I don't know value of last **float**. I only know  `["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, ]`.

```
if ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, ???? ] in l:
    pass
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the last element is a float?

Comment: I know that last element is float but I don't know its value.

Comment: Are you trying to find the value of that last element in each list?

Comment: After scratching my head for 10 minutes, I figured **OP wants to Find partial-match to item in list-of-lists**. Where "partial match" means compare only the first 4 of 5 items for equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a dummy class which compares equal to everything. Then you can use it as a kind of wildcard in your `in` condition.

```
class Dummy:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

l = [["08:00", "09:00", 60, False, 1.0],
     ["09:00", "10:00", 60, False, 0.3],
     ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, 2.0],]

if ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, Dummy() ] in l:
    print "found"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
# The input.
l = [["08:00", "09:00", 60, False, 1.0],
     ["09:00", "10:00", 60, False, 0.3],
     ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False, 2.0],]

# The pattern you want to match.
pattern = ["12:00", "13:00", 60, False]

# Make a list of all comparisons.
result = [pattern == e[:4] for e in l]

# Test.
if any(result):
    pass
```